# What are _xlfn and _xlpm in excel mean?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just received an excel and see there are some formulas including some "_xlfn" and "s
H?

Ggpaspr*`emphasized text`*x
Xxx
X[vs](https://Z)
_xlpm". What do they mean?

Comment: Check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks mate, I also checked this one. But I am using the most updated 365 mac version already and I want to use LET function. Are there extra step needa do? I see LET is new function for 365 subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel uses `_xlfn.` for formulas and `_xlpm.` for `LET` & `LAMBDA` arguments for backwards compatibility.

It informs previous versions of Excel that *this is a valid formula in the future*, and Excel shows the stored values instead of errors.