# Conditional formatting highlight only invalid cells

Tags: java, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

I am creating below conditional formatting rule in Apache POI.

### Issue

Expected:

- The formula should highlight only invalid values in column 'J'.

Actual:

- But all values of the entire column 'J' get highlighted, even for valid values.

#### Formula

```java
String kkf="IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J4)),ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(FILTERXML(\"<t><s>\"&SUBSTITUTE(J4,\",\",\"</s><s>\")&\"</s></t>\",\"//s\"),FILTERXML(\"<t><s>\"&SUBSTITUTE(PossibleValues!$D$2,\",\",\"</s><s>\")&\"</s></t>\",\"//s\"),0))),\"\"),TRUE())";
```

### Full Code

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.json.CDL;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import  java.io.*;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ComparisonOperator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ConditionalFormattingRule;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.SheetConditionalFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

public class Red {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

String str="{\"rulesetgroupname\":\"Coastal122\",\"downloadtype\":\"Template\",\"rulesetid\":\"638a0ac02944f902b1eebab3\",\"rulesetversion\":\"0.1\",\"rulegroupid\":\"638a09f28bd88c16a76fa599\",\"product\":\"CAT\",\"ruletype\":\"ERWR\",\"dataobjects\":\"Location 24,Class Codes 24,BPP Covg 24,Building Covg 24,Building 24,Policy 24\",\"ruletemplateversion\":\"1\",\"ruleTemplaeResponseId\":\"638a09f28bd88c16a76fa599\",\"dataobject\":\"Location 24\",\"rulegroup\":\"CAT Testing122\",\"metadataheaders\":[\"Rule Name\",\"Rule Label\",\"Modified By\",\"Modified At\",\"Rule ID\",\"Rule Status (Add/Change/Expire/Verify)\",\"Effective Date [MM/DD/YYYY]\",\"Expiration Date [MM/DD/YYYY]\",\"Has Rule Changed?\"],\"conditionheaders\":[{\"label\":\"State\",\"type\":\"Collection\",\"name\":\"State\",\"dataobject\":\"Location 24\",\"values\":\"NC,SC,TX,VA,MA,GA,AL,IL,DE,NY,MS,NH,RI,ME,FL,MN,CT,NJ,MD\"},{\"label\":\"Counties\",\"type\":\"Collection\",\"name\":\"Counties\",\"dataobject\":\"Location 24\",\"values\":\"\"},{\"label\":\"Zip Codes\",\"type\":\"Collection\",\"name\":\"ZipCodes\",\"dataobject\":\"Location 24\",\"values\":\"\"}],\"outcomeheaders\":[{\"label\":\"Output\",\"type\":\"String\",\"name\":\"RuleCode\",\"dataobject\":\"Location 24\"}]}";

        JSONObject output;
        try {
            output = new JSONObject(str);

          
            
            String filename = "D:\\project\\excel\\color.xlsx" ;
            

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            String rulegroup = output.getString("rulegroup");
            String downloadtype = output.getString("downloadtype");
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Ruleset");

            sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(10);

            ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> nameheaders = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Top Element Font

            Font font31 = workbook.createFont();
            font31.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
            font31.setBold(true);
            
            XSSFCellStyle style12 = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style12.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.PALE_BLUE.getIndex());
            style12.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style12.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style12.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            style12.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style12.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style12.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style12.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style12.setWrapText(true);
            style12.setFont(font31);
            
            XSSFCellStyle style13 = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style13.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
            style13.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style13.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style13.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            style13.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style13.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style13.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style13.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style13.setWrapText(true);
            style13.setFont(font31);

            XSSFCellStyle style14 = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font32 = workbook.createFont();
            font32.setBold(true);
            font32.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
            style14.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style14.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style14.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style14.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style14.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style14.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            style14.setWrapText(true);
            style14.setFont(font32);
            // Get Top elements

            String product = output.getString("product");
            String ruletype = output.getString("ruletype");
            String dataobject = output.getString("dataobjects");
            String rulesetid = output.getString("rulesetid");
            String rulesetversion = output.getString("rulesetversion");
            String rulegroupid = output.getString("rulegroupid");
            String ruletemplateversion = output.getString("ruletemplateversion");
            String rulesetgroupname = output.getString("rulesetgroupname");

            XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Product/Process");
            rowhead.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue(product);
            rowhead.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("RuleType");
            rowhead.getCell(2).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue(ruletype);
            rowhead.getCell(3).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("DataObject");
            rowhead.getCell(4).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue(dataobject);
            rowhead.getCell(5).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(6).setCellValue("RuleTemplate");
            rowhead.getCell(6).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(7).setCellValue(rulegroup);
            rowhead.getCell(7).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(8).setCellValue("RulesetID");
            rowhead.getCell(8).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(9).setCellValue(rulesetid);
            rowhead.getCell(9).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(10).setCellValue("RuleSetVersion");
            rowhead.getCell(10).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(11).setCellValue(rulesetversion);
            rowhead.getCell(11).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(12).setCellValue("RuleTemplateID");
            rowhead.getCell(12).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(13).setCellValue(rulegroupid);
            rowhead.getCell(13).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(14).setCellValue("RuleTemplateVersion");
            rowhead.getCell(14).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(15).setCellValue(ruletemplateversion);
            rowhead.getCell(15).setCellStyle(style13);
            rowhead.createCell(16).setCellValue("RuleSetGroupName");
            rowhead.getCell(16).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead.createCell(17).setCellValue(rulesetgroupname);
            rowhead.getCell(17).setCellStyle(style12);

            rowhead.setHeightInPoints((2 * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));

            JSONArray metadataheader = output.getJSONArray("metadataheaders");
            JSONArray conditionheader = output.getJSONArray("conditionheaders");
            JSONArray outcomeheader = output.getJSONArray("outcomeheaders");

            Integer metheadcount = metadataheader.length();
            Integer conheadcount = conditionheader.length();
            Integer outheadcount = outcomeheader.length();

            metadataheader.getString(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < metadataheader.length(); i++) {
                headers.add(metadataheader.getString(i));
                nameheaders.add(metadataheader.getString(i));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < conditionheader.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json = conditionheader.getJSONObject(i);
                String conname = json.getString("label");
                String contype = json.getString("type");
                String dataobject1 = json.getString("dataobject");
                contype = "[" + contype + "]";
                String fnl = dataobject1 + "." + conname + " " + contype;

                headers.add(fnl);

                nameheaders.add(conname);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < outcomeheader.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json = outcomeheader.getJSONObject(i);
//              if(json.isEmpty()) {
//                  throw new Exception("Outcome Attributes filed should not be empty");
//              } 
                String conname = json.getString("label");
                String contype = json.getString("type");
                String dataobject1 = json.getString("dataobject");
                contype = "[" + contype + "]";
                String fnl = dataobject1 + "." + conname + " " + contype;
                headers.add(fnl);

                nameheaders.add(conname);

            }

            // Merging Region
            // HSSFRow merge = sheet.createRow((short)1);
            Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("MetaData");

            // Merging cells by providing cell index
            sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, metheadcount - 1));
            Font font3 = workbook.createFont();
            font3.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
            font3.setBold(true);

            XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            style.setWrapText(true);

            /*
             * style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             */
            style.setFont(font3);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            // style.setFont(headerFont);
            // style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(metheadcount);
            cell1.setCellValue("Conditional Attributes");

            if (conheadcount > 1) {
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, metheadcount, metheadcount + conheadcount - 1));
            }

            XSSFCellStyle style1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font1 = workbook.createFont();
            font1.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
            font1.setBold(true);
            style1.setFont(font1);
            style1.setWrapText(true);
            style1.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIGHT_ORANGE.getIndex());
            style1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style1.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style1.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            /*
             * style1.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style1.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style1.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style1.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             */
            cell1.setCellStyle(style1);

            Cell cell2 = row.createCell(metheadcount + conheadcount);
            cell2.setCellValue("Outcome Attributes");
            if (outheadcount > 1) {
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, metheadcount + conheadcount,
                        metheadcount + conheadcount + outheadcount - 1));
            }
            XSSFCellStyle style2 = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font2 = workbook.createFont();
            font2.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
            font2.setBold(true);

            style2.setFont(font2);
            style2.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
            style2.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style2.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style2.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            style2.setWrapText(true);
            /*
             * style2.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style2.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style2.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             * style2.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
             */
            cell2.setCellStyle(style2);

            row.setHeightInPoints((2 * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));

            /*
             * HSSFCellStyle style22 = workbook.createCellStyle(); Font font22 =
             * workbook.createFont();
             * font22.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
             * font22.setBold(true); style22.setFont(font22);
             * style22.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
             */

            XSSFCellStyle style22 = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font22 = workbook.createFont();
            font22.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
            font22.setBold(true);
            style22.setFont(font22);
            style22.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style22.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style22.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style22.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            style22.setWrapText(true);
            // style22.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.WHITE.getIndex());
            // style22.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style22.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

            XSSFRow rowheader = sheet.createRow((short) 2);

            for (int z = 0; z < headers.size(); z++) {
                rowheader.createCell(z).setCellValue(headers.get(z));
                String metaDataCellValue = rowheader.getCell(z).getStringCellValue();
                if(metaDataCellValue.equals("Rule Name") || metaDataCellValue.equals("Modified By") ||
                        metaDataCellValue.equals("Modified At") || metaDataCellValue.equals("Rule ID")) {
                    rowheader.getCell(z).setCellStyle(style13);
                } else {
                    rowheader.getCell(z).setCellStyle(style22);
                }
                

            }

            rowheader.setHeightInPoints((2 * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));

            // Get Details

            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

            if (downloadtype.equalsIgnoreCase("rulesets")) {

                JSONArray values = output.getJSONArray("values");
                if (!values.isEmpty()) {

                    short valcell = 3;

                    for (int val = 0; val < values.length(); val++) {

                        XSSFRow rowheader2 = sheet.createRow((short) valcell + val);

                        try {
                            JSONObject firstvals = values.getJSONObject(val);

                            JSONArray methead1 = firstvals.optJSONArray("metadata");
                            JSONArray conhead1 = firstvals.optJSONArray("condition");
                            JSONArray outhead1 = firstvals.optJSONArray("outcome");

                            for (int i = 0; i < methead1.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject json = methead1.getJSONObject(i);
                                String val23 = json.get("value").toString();
                                String name = "";
                                if (!json.isNull("label")) {
                                    name = (json.getString("label"));
                                } else {
                                    name = (json.getString("name"));
                                }
                                int index = nameheaders.indexOf(name);
                                rowheader2.createCell(index).setCellValue(val23);
                            }

                            for (int y = 0; y < conhead1.length(); y++) {
                                JSONObject json = conhead1.getJSONObject(y);
                                String val23 = json.get("value").toString();

                                String name = "";
                                if (!json.isNull("label")) {
                                    name = (json.getString("label"));
                                } else {
                                    name = (json.getString("name"));
                                }

                                String oper = (json.getString("operator"));
                                

                                if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("not in")) {

                                    val23 = "NOT IN(" + val23 + ")";

                                } else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("neq")) {

                                    val23 = "NOT EQUALS(" + val23 + ")";
                                } else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase(">") || oper.equalsIgnoreCase("GT") ) {

                                    val23 =  ">" + val23;
                                    
                                } else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase(">=") || oper.equalsIgnoreCase("GTE")) {

                                    val23 =  ">=" + val23;
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                }else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("<") || oper.equalsIgnoreCase("LT")) {

                                    val23 =  "<" + val23;
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                else if ( oper.equalsIgnoreCase("<=") || oper.equalsIgnoreCase("LTE")) {

                                    val23 =  "<=" + val23;
                                    
                                }

                                int index = nameheaders.indexOf(name);
                                if (index > 0) {
                                    rowheader2.createCell(index).setCellValue(val23);
                                }
                            }

                            for (int za = 0; za < outhead1.length(); za++) {
                                JSONObject json = outhead1.getJSONObject(za);
                                String val23 = json.get("value").toString();

                                String name = "";
                                if (!json.isNull("label")) {
                                    name = (json.getString("label"));
                                } else {
                                    name = (json.getString("name"));
                                }

                                int index = nameheaders.indexOf(name);

                                if (index > 0) {
                                    rowheader2.createCell(index).setCellValue(val23);
                                }

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            String error = e.getMessage();
                            throw new Exception(error);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // String error = e.getMessage();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }

                } //

            }


            

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            evaluator.evaluateAll();

            // Duplicate Highlighter

            String lcollett = "";
            String csv1 = "";
            SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
            int s1 = sheet.getNumMergedRegions();

            for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
                CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn();
                int rowNum = region.getFirstRow();
                String val1 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colIndex));
                if (val1.contains("MetaData")) {
                    int fcol = sheet.getMergedRegion(i).getFirstColumn();
                    int lcol = sheet.getMergedRegion(i).getLastColumn();
                    lcollett = CellReference.convertNumToColString(lcol);
                    for (i = fcol; i <= lcol; i++) {
                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
                    }

                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
                CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn();
                int rowNum = region.getFirstRow();
                String val1 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colIndex));
                ArrayList<String> xsdf = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (val1.contains("Conditional")) {
                    int fcol = sheet.getMergedRegion(i).getFirstColumn();
                    int lcol = sheet.getMergedRegion(i).getLastColumn();
                    String fcollett = "";
                    lcollett = CellReference.convertNumToColString(lcol);
                    for (i = fcol; i <= lcol; i++) {
                        fcollett = CellReference.convertNumToColString(i);
                        if (i == lcol) {
                            xsdf.add("$" + fcollett + "$4:$" + fcollett + "$10000,\"*\"&$" + fcollett + "4&\"*\"");
                        } else {
                            xsdf.add("$" + fcollett + "$4:$" + fcollett + "$10000,$" + fcollett + "4");
                        }

                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);

                    }

                    csv1 = String.join(",", xsdf);
                    csv1 = "COUNTIFS(" + csv1 + ")>1";
                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
                CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn();
                int rowNum = region.getFirstRow();
                String val1 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colIndex));
                if (val1.contains("Outcome")) {
                    int fcol = sheet.getMergedRegion(i).getFirstColumn();
                    int lcol = sheet.getMergedRegion(i).getLastColumn();
                    lcollett = CellReference.convertNumToColString(lcol);
                    for (i = fcol; i <= lcol; i++) {
                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
                    }

                }

            }

            ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(csv1);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FontFormatting font = rule1.createFontFormatting();
            font.setFontStyle(false, true);
            font.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);
            String cellrangeadd = "A4:" + lcollett + "10000";
            CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[] { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(cellrangeadd) };
            sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
            
            // Sheet 3
            
            SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCFa = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
            
            XSSFSheet sheet21 = workbook.createSheet("PossibleValues");

            sheet21.setColumnWidth(0, 20 * 256);
            sheet21.setColumnWidth(1, 50 * 256);
            
            XSSFRow rowhead33 = sheet21.createRow((short) 0);

            rowhead33.createCell(0).setCellValue("DataObject");
            rowhead33.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead33.createCell(1).setCellValue("AttributeName");
            rowhead33.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead33.createCell(2).setCellValue("DataType");
            rowhead33.getCell(2).setCellStyle(style14);
            rowhead33.createCell(3).setCellValue("PossibleValues");
            rowhead33.getCell(3).setCellStyle(style14);

            
            int attcell=1;
            ArrayList<String> xkdf = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < conditionheader.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json = conditionheader.getJSONObject(i);
                String conname = json.getString("label");
                String contype = json.getString("type");
                String dataobject1 = json.getString("dataobject");
                String pv = json.getString("values");
            String  contypea = "[" + contype + "]";
            String fnl = dataobject1 + "." + conname + " " + contypea;
            
                xkdf.add(fnl);
                

                XSSFRow rowhead334 = sheet21.createRow((short) attcell + i);
                     
                rowhead334.createCell(0).setCellValue(dataobject1);
                rowhead334.createCell(1).setCellValue(conname);
                rowhead334.createCell(2).setCellValue(contype);
                rowhead334.createCell(3).setCellValue(pv);


            }
            
    
            String kkf = "IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J4)),ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(FILTERXML(\"<t><s>\"&SUBSTITUTE(J4,\",\",\"</s><s>\")&\"</s></t>\",\"//s\"),FILTERXML(\"<t><s>\"&SUBSTITUTE(PossibleValues!$D$2,\",\",\"</s><s>\")&\"</s></t>\",\"//s\"),0))),\"\"),TRUE())";
            ConditionalFormattingRule rule13 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(kkf);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FontFormatting font535 = rule13.createFontFormatting();
            font535.setFontStyle(false, true);
            font535.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.RED.index);
            
            String cellrangeadd2 = "J4:J10000";
            CellRangeAddress[] regionssd = new CellRangeAddress[] { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(cellrangeadd2) };
            sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regionssd, rule13);

              FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
              workbook.write(fileOut); 
              fileOut.close(); 
              workbook.close();
  
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");   

          
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }

}
```

### Required manual post-production in Excel

Now  I did the below steps

1. Add three values in column 'J' named "State". All cells are getting highlighted, see image below:

[image: all cells get highlighted, no matter if valid]

2. Click Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > Select Rule (Format Red) > Edit Rules > OK > Apply > OK

After this action the column values are getting highlighted correctly.

[image]

### Question

Is there anything I missed in my Java code?
How do I avoid this manual activity in Excel?

Comment: You will need to elaborate on the `it should highlight the selected cells in column 'J' but the entire column 'J' is getting highlighted` part. The screenshot shows the same values over and over, so no wonder they all get red font. And from what I can tell, it is not an issue with cell range you are highlighting. So you should also elaborate on what actually the issue is. Also some raw data would help to reproduce the issue

Comment: Can't reproduce anything in excel with that information. However, you might want to evaluate formulas before writing to file: `workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have updated the post and added the xml related information. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @XtremeBaumer By the way evaluate formula didn't help.

Comment: I strongly believe that you are either omitting crucial information or that the formula is broken as it is. Unless you can provide a reproducible example I don't see any way we can help you

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have added the full code for reference with all snapshots.

Comment: Did you validated if the formula is applied to all the rows of column J ?

Comment: Try to replace your formula by: `String kkf ="IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J4)),NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(J4,PossibleValues!$D$2)))),TRUE,FALSE)";` It works for me (but it is case sensitive)

Comment: @PhilippeFery Thanks for the reply.. it worked..but one catch is the formula u provided will handle one value at a time. If I enter comma-separate ones like (FL,MD) it is highlighting that as well. The expectation is to handle comma-separated values also

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at it

Comment: Should mention related your question for [conditional formatting comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370667/apache-poi-conditional-formatting-for-comma-separated-values-mismatch), particularly if this is a requirement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

The problem is with the `FILTERXML` function used in your conditional formatting. This should be prefixed `_xlfn` in XML sheet storage. To make it work your formula should be changed to following:

```java
String kkf = "IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J4)),ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(_xlfn.FILTERXML(\"<t><s>\"&SUBSTITUTE(J4,\",\",\"</s><s>\")&\"</s></t>\",\"//s\"),_xlfn.FILTERXML(\"<t><s>\"&SUBSTITUTE(PossibleValues!$D$2,\",\",\"</s><s>\")&\"</s></t>\",\"//s\"),0))),\"\"),TRUE())";
```

#### Reason

[FILTERXML function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) was introduced in Excel 2013. So it was introduced after Microsoft had published the `Office Open XML` file format for Microsoft Office files in 2006 for Office 2007. To mark such later introduced functions, Microsoft decided to prefix them with `_xlfn` in XML storage. After reading the XML, the Excel GUI knows whether the function is known in that Excel version or not. If yes, the prefix gets removed and the function name gets localized (e.g. in German Excel: to `XMLFILTER`). If not, the prefix remains and the user also knows that this function is unknown in that Excel version. See [Issue: An _xlfn. prefix is displayed in front of a formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025).

#### Why we need the storage formula version?

In Apache POI `Cell.setCellFormula` as well as `SheetConditionalFormatting.createConditionalFormattingRule` sets the formula string into the XML directly. So that string must be exactly as it shall be stored in XML.

#### Learn more about this by inspecting the file-formats

`Office Open XML` files, and so also `*.xlsx` files, are ZIP archives containing XML files and other files into a specific directory structure. So one simply can unzip a `*.xlsx` file to have a look into.

So after creating your `color.xlsx` using your code, unzip it and have a look into `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`.

You will find something like:

```
<conditionalFormatting sqref="J4:J10000">
 <cfRule type="expression" dxfId="1" priority="2">
  <formula>
   <![CDATA[ IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J4)),ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(J4,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(PossibleValues!$D$2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0))),""),TRUE()) ]]>
  </formula>
 </cfRule>
</conditionalFormatting>
```

And this does not work in Excel.

Now open the `color.xlsx` in Excel and make it work. Then save the the `color.xlsx`, unzip it again and have a look into `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`.

You will find something like:

```
<x14:conditionalFormattings>
 <x14:conditionalFormatting xmlns:xm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main">
  <x14:cfRule type="expression" priority="2" id="{00000000-000E-0000-0000-000002000000}">
   <xm:f>IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J4)),ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(_xlfn.FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(J4,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),_xlfn.FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(PossibleValues!$D$2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0))),""),TRUE())</xm:f>
  ...
  </x14:cfRule>
  ...
 </x14:conditionalFormatting>
</x14:conditionalFormattings>
```

This shows the `_xlfn` prefix before `FILTERXML` in formula string.

It also shows that a totally different version of conditional formatting is used. But that's a secondary problem. The prefixed version of the formula string also works using as formula string within the old version of `conditionalFormatting`. But, of course that is not guaranteed in all cases. So to be on save side for all cases, one of two possibilities must be given:

- either one avoids using all Excel functions introduced after publishing `Office Open XML` in 2006 (Office 2007)
- or Apache POI has to fully support all changes Microsoft made after publishing `Office Open XML` in 2006 (Office 2007).

To fulfill the latter Apache POI is far away. It not even supports all features of Office 2007 up to now.

Comment: For the prefix see also [What are _xlfn and _xlpm in excel mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294341/what-are-xlfn-and-xlpm-in-excel-mean)

Comment: @Axel Thank you so much.. Finally got the solution and also thanks for providing us very detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

If using VBA is an acceptable solution for you, then a possible solution would be to create an .xlsm file containing the functions needed for conditional formatting.

1. Create manually the color.xlsm file
2. Add the 2 empty sheets "Ruleset" and "PossibleValues"
3. Open VBA editor
4. In sheet "Ruleset" add following Sub:

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
>     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$j$4:$j$1000")) Is Nothing Then
>         Highlight Target
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

5. Create a VBA Module and add following Sub...

> ```
> Sub Highlight(ByVal Cell As Range)
>     Dim Entry() As String
>     Entry = Split(Cell.Value, ",")     
>     Dim StatesString As String
>     StatesString = UCase(Worksheets("PossibleValues").Range("D2").Value)
>     Dim States() As String
>     States = Split(StatesString, ",")
>
>     Dim Matches As Integer
>     Matches = 0
>     For EntryIdx = 0 To UBound(Entry)
>         If (IsInArray(Entry(EntryIdx), States)) Then
>             Matches = Matches + 1
>         End If
>     Next EntryIdx
>
>     If (UBound(Entry) + 1 = Matches) Then
>         Cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
>     Else
>         Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
>     End If End Sub
> ```

...and the following function:

> ```
> Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
>     'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
>     'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
>     'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
>     'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
>     Dim element As Variant
>     On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
>     For Each element In arr
>         If element = valToBeFound Then
>             IsInArray = True
>             Exit Function
>         End If
>     Next element
> Exit Function
> IsInArrayError:
> On Error GoTo 0
> IsInArray = False
> End Function
> ```

6. Finally, you will need to adapt your code to open this manually created .xlsm file rather than creating it programmatically.

Hope it helps